# nginx troubleshooting Ubuntu 16.04 ( dependency problems)

Tags: 16.04, server, apt, nginx

Trying to install a LEMP for the first time with no prior experience using this tutorial: [How To Install Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)

running  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on a fresh instance (scaleway VPS)

Since I was getting errors I tried removing and reinstalling nginx

```
apt purge nginx
apt autoremove
apt install nginx
```

but I'm still having issues

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-full (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:
 nginx depends on nginx-core (>= 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) | nginx-full (>= 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) | nginx-light (>= 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) | nginx-extras (>= 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4); however:
  Package nginx-core is not installed.
  Package nginx-full is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.
 nginx depends on nginx-core (<< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~) | nginx-full (<< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~) | nginx-extras (<< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~); however:
  Package nginx-core is not installed.
  Package nginx-full is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-full
 nginx
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

running systemctl status nginx.service:

```
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-01-09 22:20:18 UTC; 5min ago
  Process: 15561 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

I also tried
sudo apt-get install nginx-full which has the following output:

```
dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-full
 nginx
```

Comment: Try running `sudo nginx`.  Does it give any errors?

Comment: @ThomasWard `nginx: [emerg] socket() [::]:80 failed (97: Address family not supported by protocol)`

Answer (score 0):

Check /var/log/nginx/error.log
There might be some clue in there for you.  I had this:

### 2017/02/04 14:55:09 [emerg] 25011#25011: mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/microcache" failed (2: No such file or directory)

So I manually created the /var/cache/nginx subdirectory and re-ran the install and it succeeded.